# bundled NPAPI plugin in sandboxed cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, webview, npapi, browser-plugin, appstore-sandbox

I'm working on a cocoa app using Xcode 4.5.1. My app uses a webview and bundles a plugin to use with that webview.

When I'm compiling my code and running my app, it works fine, and the plugin is loaded and used in the webview.

However, if I enable the sandbox environment for my app, it stops working. The plugin is not loaded.

When running out of sandbox, I get this log from my plugin:

```
10/22/12 4:40:54.041 PM WebKitPluginHost[43018]: Instantiating Plugin
```

When running in the sandbox, I don't get anything from my plugin, but the webview does show a blank box where my plugin view should be. It does not show a Missing plugin message as it would if the plugin was not here.

I tried to add this to the entitlements of my app:

```
com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent
```

as a string to the

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name array
```

but with no luck.

Do you know how I can debug this?

Answer (score 1):

See my response to [How do I add a Webkit plugin to my sandboxed OS X app WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591456/how-do-i-add-a-webkit-plugin-to-my-sandboxed-os-x-app-webview/14466399#14466399)

In summary: running in 32-bit mode will work, because plugins run in the same process as the host application. In 64-bit mode, it appears the plugin agent lacks permission to launch the plugin process, causing the load to fail silently.