# iOS 9 NPAPI in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios9, npapi

Comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708342/ios-safari-support-plugins) state "As of iOS 9, browser plugins are supported" however I haven't been able to find a real reference.

Is it possible to package a C++ NPAPI plugin in an iOS 9 iPhone app? We have a [firebreath](http://www.firebreath.org) plugin we would like to use in conjuncture with a UIWebView.

Comment: According to [Webkit plugin to my sandboxed OS X app WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591456/how-do-i-add-a-webkit-plugin-to-my-sandboxed-os-x-app-webview/14466399#14466399) bundling a browser NPAPI plugin can be done in the [`Content/Plugins`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html) folder? We will attempt this and report back results

Comment: I will be very interested to hear the results of your search; I can't find any references to it either